# ultrafilters as linear orders

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, order-theory, model-theory, filters

In Henson's *Model Theory* [lecture notes](https://www.math.mcgill.ca/atserunyan/Courses/2016F.Math571.MT/Henson--van%20den%20Dries.pdf) I found an exercise quite early on (1.30, p. 12) that prove too difficult for me. It goes like this:

> Let $L$ be the first order language whose only nonlogical symbol is
> the binary predicate symbol $<$. Let $\mathcal{A}=(\mathbb{N},<)$ and
> let $\mathcal{B}=\mathcal{A}^{I} / U$ be an ultrapower of
> $\mathcal{A}$ where $I$ is countably infinite and $U$ is a
> nonprincipal ultrafilter on $I$.
>
> - Show that $\mathcal{B}$ is a linear ordering.
> - Show that the range of the diagonal embedding of $\mathcal{A}$ into $\mathcal{B}$ is a proper initial segment of $\mathcal{B}$. Give an
>   explicit description of an element of $B$ that is not in the range of
>   this embedding.
> - Show that $\mathcal{N}$ is not a well ordering; that is, describe an infinite descending sequence in $\mathcal{N}$.

For the first point, I realize I "just" need to check whether it is reflexive, transitive, antisymmetric and strongly connected. But I do not see how to even treat the definition of $\mathcal{B}$. Then I am completely lost at the second dot.

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Do you know what is meant by "the ultrapower of $A$"? Do you know Łós's Theorem?

Comment: I do, but I do not see how Łoś applies to the first one as @markvs says

Answer (score 4):

The first part is just an easy application of Łoś's theorem but is trivially proved directly.

The second part. If $a=((n))$ is an element of the diagonal image of  $A$ and $b=((b_i))<a$, then almost for all $i$ $b_i<n$. Then there are only finitely many different $b_i$. Since the ultrafilter is not principal, there is a set $S$ from the ultrafilter and $s<n$ such that $b_i=s$ for all $i\in S$. Then $b=((s))$ belongs to the image of the diagonal embedding. QED

The third part is straightforward: just find an infinite descendent sequence starting with $(1,2,2^2, 2^{2^2}, 2^{2^{2^2}},...)$ (again using the fact that the ultrafilter is not principal).

Comment: Sorry, but I do not see how Łoś could be applied here

Comment: "Linear order" is a first order sentence. Since $A$ is a linear order, $B$ is also a linear order under the natural $<$, by  Łoś

Comment: ahh ok, thank you! One more question: what do you mean by double brackets, as in $a =((n))$? Henson does not use this formalism

Comment: $((n))$ is the infinite sequence where all members are equal to $n$. "Almost for all" means that the set of indices for which this is true belongs to the ultrafilter.